# In NSLog, methods return an upsidedown question mark

Tags: ios, objective-c, boolean, string-formatting, nslog

I can access a property declared like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter = isPrivateSickDay) BOOL   privateSickDay; 

- (BOOL)isPrivateShortDay;
```

Using the following:

```
int sick = aModel.privateSickDay;


NSLog(@"zero for not sick, one for sick %d", sick);
```

However, when I try to use the method, I get an upside down question mark in my NSLog:

```
BOOL shortness = [aModel isPrivateShortDay];

NSLog(@"shortness: %c", shortness);
```

So, I put some NSLogs into the method itself...

```
- (BOOL)isPrivateShortDay {
NSLog(@"Shortness called");
NSLog(@"FfDateStatus_ShortWorkingDay_Private: %d",FfDateStatus_ShortWorkingDay_Private);
NSLog(@"_shortnessStatus: %c",self->_shortnessStatus);
return (FfDateStatus_ShortWorkingDay_Private == self->_shortnessStatus);
 }
```

And `_shortnessStatus:` also returns an upsidedown question mark.  What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: `%c` is the format for printing a character. The character with ascii value 1 (I suspect that's the value of your BOOL) is not printable and shows a character representing an unprintable character. `%d` will instead output 0 for false and 1 for true.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just change `%c` to `%i` in the NSLog statement.